# Alphavantage library installation issue on conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda

I am trying to install alphavantage library on a conda environment downgraded to py3.5 and it throws exception while installing. TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument ‘transport_encoding’
Also tried cloning the repo and installing via pip didn't work.
[image]

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Users\vignesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

Comment: Can you please copy the text of error message into your post, including the exact command you used that produced the error?

Comment: I added a screenshot please check it.

Comment: Please do not post error messages in screenshots. Search engines cannot index the text in the image, so this post will never help anyone else, and blind users cannot read the post at all. Please copy the text of the error message into your post.

Comment: I didn't know will edit it but any possible solutions

Comment: You also need to say how you made the environment and what command you're using that raises this error. Otherwise, it is impossible to tell. In general, one should prefer using conda to install packages rather than pip, but that might not help here (and I don't think this package is available as a conda package anyways)